# Is it possible to play with Google Mirror API without having the device?

Tags: google-api, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I've been reading the documentation and playing at https://glass-java-starter-demo.appspot.com/ but it seems there is no way to further investigate since when following the instructions from https://developers.google.com/glass/playground at my https://code.google.com/apis/console/ the Google Mirror switch is not showing up. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 10):

According to issue #2 on the tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=2) access is currently restricted to members of the Explorer program with Glass.

Comment: At Google I/O glass session here - nothing about turning on Mirror API for non-explorers, and the glass desk can't help with it, either.

Answer (score 6):

With the release of XE12, the Mirror API is open to all developers. However, it's still very important to test your Glassware on Glass before distributing it.

Comment: My i/o 2013 ticket is purchased, the flight from Louisville, Kentucky is booked, and I just got back last night from Kansas City where my wife and I bought a house to relocate for Google Fiber. All I ask is that you let me build my BasicMath application [ https://plus.google.com/117151337541845371124/posts/jd8rohyQQSf ]  before I/O 13 @Jenny!! :)

Comment: HoldTheLine I am unable to get the link between your comment with the answer of Jenny :O !  And Jenny thanks a lot for your description as well as documentation link you have provided.

Comment: It seems possible now.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this.
Have a  look  at  https://github.com/scarygami/mirror-api

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use your Android phone as a Google Glass. Look at this guide [Google Glass XE7 APKs](https://github.com/zhuowei/Xenologer)

After installing those apks in your phone. Lounch Glass Home app.
Then go to [MyGlass](https://glass.google.com/myglass) application and configure your Glass.

Then register for Google Mirror API and follow this quick starter guide
[Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/index)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible now: https://developers.google.com/glass/devprev. Similar answer as Jenny but updated.