# Google Glass Development for another

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

Wondering if anyone knows about developing a Google Glass app for another person. Someone who is in the Glass Explorer program has asked me to help them with developing an app (which I'm happy to do) but it looks like I will need to sign in as that person in the API Console. Is this correct? Is there any way for me to prototype separately?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it posible to play with Google Mirror API without having the device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028805/is-it-posible-to-play-with-google-mirror-api-without-having-the-device)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a way to do this without logging in as your colleague. Join the project team on the API console. Just follow these steps:

1. Have your Explorer friend create an [API Console](https://developers.google.com/console) project and enable the Google Mirror API for that project from the [services panel](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#services).
2. Have them go to the [team panel](https://code.google.com/apis/console/#%3ateam) for that project. Have them add your account to the project's team.

This enables you to develop on the same project, but since you're not an Explorer you cannot enable or disable the Mirror API for this project.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much Jenny. We'll follow this path.

Comment: Jenny your answer is very much helpful and resourceful. Thanks a lot.